# How can I check if a value exists in 2 different fields with a query in Parse?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I need to do a query on an object in parse to see either of 2 fields contain a value. The value is a PFUser object. I presume I need some kind of OR statement but I don't know how to do that.

Here's the code I have so far..

```
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameTradeObject"];

    [query whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];

    [query whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [query includeKey:@"fromUser"];
    [query includeKey:@"fromVillage"];

    [query includeKey:@"toUser"];
    [query includeKey:@"toVillage"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *PUObjects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
```

What I need is to know if the current user Object exists in either of the fromUser or toUser fields. I think it might have to be done with an NSPredicate but I don't know how to build the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1, query2]]` to combine two queries.

```
  PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameTradeObject"];
  [query1 whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];
  [query1 whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

  PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameTradeObject"];
  [query2 whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];
  [query2 whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1, query2]];
  [query includeKey:@"fromUser"];
  [query includeKey:@"fromVillage"];
  [query includeKey:@"toUser"];
  [query includeKey:@"toVillage"];
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which will typically be faster to execute, is to store both users in a single array. You might consider:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassname:@"GameTradeObject"];
// array equalTo string returns all objects where the array contains the string
[query whereKey:@"users" equalTo:PFUser.currentUser];
[query includeKey:@"users"];
[query includeKey:@"villages"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:...];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement below way;

```
  PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameTradeObject"];
  [query1 whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
  [query1 whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];
  PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameTradeObject"];
  [query2 whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
  [query2 whereKey:@"region" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:region]];
  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1, query2]];
```

And you won't need to use second time includeKey because you filtered on query1 and query2 as fromUser and toUser columns.